# MSSQL server syntax checking, targeting multiple environments in one script

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a really irritating problem to have that springs from poor process, I know, but it's a problem I am currently saddled with none the less.

I descended into madness when the schema changed for half of our environments but not the other half.  One half now have an extra field.  So there's a basic insertion script that needs to run in both environments

ex:

```
insert into Tbl values ('foo')
```

but on the other environments it needs to be

```
insert into Tbl values ('foo','bar')
```

I tried solving this with an 'if' since we have a table that identifies what environment you are in

```
if (select name from environment) in ('local','local2')  
insert into Tbl values ('foo')  
else  
insert into Tbl values ('foo, 'bar')
```

Unfortunately, MS SQL server syntax checks my entire script, and notes that the else portion doesn't match the schema of the current table.

How can I handle this? The requirements are basically: This has to be a single script that runs in both environments.  Is this possible?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the syntax checking you might need to use dynamic SQL:

```
if (select name from environment) in ('local','local2')
  execute('insert into Tbl values (''foo'')')
else
  execute('insert into Tbl values (''foo'', ''bar'')')
```

The syntax gets checked only when the inner statement is executed.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using dynamic sql to circumvent the syntax checking:

```
if (select name from environment) in ('local','local2')
exec sp_executesql N'insert into Tbl values (''foo'')'
else
exec sp_executesql N'insert into Tbl values (''foo'', ''bar'')'
```